# Float Property: Shows Incorrect Decimal Value

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties

I have a script that is setting some custom properties on an object. The properties are being assigned just fine and can be accessed with the proper floating point value. But the Custom Properties UI display shows the decimal value incorrectly as x.000. (See image)
[image: Custom Properties Display Incorrect Float Values]

How do I get the values to show up properly in the UI panel?

Comment: What's the code you Are using to define the property?

Comment: ob['property_name'] = 1234.5678901

Comment: When I run this code:

`import bpy  ob = bpy.context.active_object  ob['property'] = 987654.321`

The Custom Properties shows the value as 987654.313. How is it getting that value?

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug. Check the bug tracker and see if it's been reported. If not, it's probably a good candidate for reporting. Otherwise I think the next step is to post your complete code.

Comment: Looks a little larger than its maximum.  Agree with @Matt post your display code.

Comment: I logged a bug report, but it got closed citing floating point precision as the culprit. I disagree, as the value stored within the property is correct when accessed through the Python Console. It's only displayed incorrectly in the UI, as shown here: http://www.skwerm.com/public/Property2.png

Comment: At what precision is it incorrect, 1.123, 10.123, 100.123, ...  1000000.123 ?

Comment: According to the dev who was assigned the bug report (and subsequently closed it as invalid) says that it's got something to do with floating point precision when drawing the UI. Personally, I'd still call this a bug, since you would think that the UI should be able to accurately display the property value stored with the object. But I suppose if the dev says it's not a bug, who am I to argue?